# How to create sound sequencer/mixer in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I want to create sound sequencer in flash with as3.

Can someone point me in the right direction.
I guess I would need to use some sort of array with all the sounds, then on enterframe I would check my grid, with ticked boxes and play the sound if it is ticked and playhead is over the particular piece on a grid....

Here's the screenshot of what Im trying to make.

[image]

Some pseudo code, link to tutorial or just advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 100 different ways to achieve the above result, firstly i would proberly have all the sound files in an array then you could  use a hittest function.

so if the playheadMovieClip touches current DrumMovieclip ,play sound. This way its easy to control the tempo aswell by controlling playheadMovieClip.x +=1 or +=2.

I wouldnt use an Enterframe function other than to load the sounds and graphics.

If you need help with it upload your grid somewhere and i will add some code for you.